# Implementation of unified standard class library for LLVM

Tags: jvm, llvm, clr

Virtual machines like the JVM and .NET CLR come with their own standard class libraries. The classes from these libraries can be utilised from any language that compiles to the corresponding machine's bytecode.

Is it possible to implement a similar class library for the LLVM so that the classes from such a library can be utilised from any language that compiles to LLVM bytecode similarly to the aforementioned classes of the JVM and .NET CLR class libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Raw LLVM IR isn't suitable for such task, as it's not cross-platform, nor machine-independent. You might look for things like [HLVM](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/hlvm/) and [VMKit](https://vmkit.llvm.org/), which are built on top of LLVM.